# How to cast to specific child class if only child class name is provided

Tags: java, class, casting

I have two client subclass - `ClientA` and `ClientB`, and both implements `Client`. I want to invoke correct `newCall(Request)` by supplying client String name.

For example,
 `ClientClassFinder.getClientClassFromName("ClientA").newCall(request)`.

However, it looks like `ClientClassFinder.getClientClassFromName("ClientA")` returns type of `Client` instead of specific client.

So how to make it work?

Actually `Client`, `ClientA`, and `ClientB` are existing, and I am not able to change them. My question is how to invoke corresponding `newCall()` by supplying client String name?

**Class Definition**

```
public class ClientClassFinder
{
    private static Map<String, Class<? extends Client>> clientNameToClassMap = new HashMap<>();

    //Static Initializers
    static
    {
        clientNameToClassMap.put("ClientA", ClientA.class);
        clientNameToClassMap.put("ClientB", ClientB.class);
    }

    public static Class<? extends Client> getClientClassFromName(String clientSimpleName)
    {
        return clientNameToClassMap.get(clientSimpleName);
    }
}

public interface Client
{
}

public class ClientA implements Client
{
    public Response newCall(Request request) {}
}

public class ClientB implements Client
{
    public Response newCall(Request request) {}
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I would consider making Client an Interface , otherwise your client code will have no clue what to do with what your getClientClassFromName returns or the contract it uses to invoke methods.

Comment: Actually Client is an interface. The reason I want to do this is Client, CleintA, and Client B are all existing. I want to find a generic and simple way to invoke corresponding `newCall` after supplying Client name.

Comment: Also, for existing `Client` interface, there is no `newCall()` defined. Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: You can cast the result. That's the only reliable way because without a common interface , you may as well return a raw Object. Generics are a compile time feature, not runtime.

Comment: Why do you not have newCall in the interface? It seems odd to spend so much effort circumventing the tools you were provided with to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, `Client` model might be more complex than I described. I will update my question to explicitly indicate `Client`, `ClientA`, and `ClientB ` are provided, and my problem is if it is possible to invoke corresponding `newCall()` by supply client name.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Would you please explain a bit more regarding "how to cast result"?

Comment: In the trivial case, `((ClientA)ClientClassFinder.getClientClassFromName("ClientA")).newCall(request)`. Otherwise you have to use reflection to get the method. Please don't do this. It stinks to high heaven.

Comment: If you add newCall to the interface, all your problems go away

Comment: @MadPhysicist Since I have more than 10 clients, if casting as `((ClientA)ClientClassFinder.getClientClassFromName("ClientA"‌​)).newCall(request)`, I have to use `if...else if` to know which client. That is the reason I post this question. Would you please suggest how to use reflection to get the method?

Comment: Tomorrow morning I will, despite my better judgement.

Comment: Then what is the use of making a client as an interface ?

Comment: You should code for interface not for implementation .

Comment: @RohitSingh Actually my job here is to dispatch request to correct client. Client model is not what I should consider or modify.

Comment: you want to invoke newCall() which will have different implementation for different client right?

Comment: you can't change interface also ? is that your requirement or u can ?

Comment: @RohitSingh Actually each newCall() is the same. But since client is different the request will be sent to different endpoint. I cannot change client interface. I am writing tool only so cannot change.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by Reflection. Check this link and understand if you want to use it or not.

http://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial

Comment: Actually reflection is able to find the class. In my example, I am only able to get class of interface `Client`, but not specific client. So I was not able to invoke `newCall()`.